# How to create a cms like wordpress that can be installed in express ?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, content-management-system

Sorry about my bad English . 
Guys i want to know how to create a cms like wordpress that can be installed by users on their host . you know what i mean ? i want to create one simple cms and give it to 100 person to install and use it just like wordpress .

Comment: This question is to broad. What have you tried? Why _"like WordPress"_, what are your needs that WordPress doesn't allow? How does is differ.

Comment: its just a example . i want to create a web application for drugstores to install and use it . i know how to create for one specific drugstore but i want to know how i can make it possible to use in  every drugstore by installing my app . in express js

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304128/how-to-create-a-cms-like-wordpress-that-can-be-installed-in-express/41304789#41304789) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at Keystone:

- http://keystonejs.com/

It's a:

> Node.js CMS & Web Application Platform
>
> The open source framework for developing database-driven websites,
>   applications and APIs in Node.js. Built on **Express** and MongoDB
>   [emphasis added]